# In Laravel, is there a way to syncWithoutDetaching and also update pivot values?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-relations

According to the API documentation:

**syncWithPivotValues**: sync the intermediate tables with a list of IDs or collection of models with the given pivot values.

**syncWithouDetaching**: sync the intermediate tables with a list of IDs without detaching.

How can I sync the intermediate tables with a list of IDs without detaching with the given pivot values?

**Example:**

The following operation will adds roles with IDs 1, 2, and 3 to the user and sets the active pivot attribute to true for these roles.

```php
$user->roles()->syncWithPivotValues([1, 2, 3], ['active' => true]);
```

The above will also sync the $user and their roles but it adds these roles without detaching any existing roles.

```php
$user->roles()->syncWithoutDetaching([1, 2, 3]);
```

What I want to do:

```php
$user->roles()->syncWithoutDetachingWithPivotValues([1, 2, 3], ['active' => true]);
```

Basically I'm looking for a way to add these roles to the $user without detaching any existing roles, but also set the active pivot attribute to true for these newly added roles.

Comment: I don't know of a way to sync and update pivot table values at the same time, but there is the [`updateExistingPivot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-a-record-on-the-intermediate-table) method, so you could do `foreach([1, 2, 3] as $pivotId) { $user->roles()->updateExistingPivot($pivotId, ['active' => true]); }`, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I use `syncWithoutDetaching` like this:

```
$user->roles()->syncWithoutDetaching([1 => ['active' => true], 2 => ['active' => true], 3 => ['active' => true]]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).